# How to run embedded TomEE for integration tests with test resources

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing

I have J2EE project based on maven. This project contains connection to database, which is set up via **resources.xml** and **persistence.xml**. Connection works fine for normal deployment.

My problem is, that i would like to run embedded TomEE server for integration tests. For these tests i need use inmemory database.

To start TomEE i use combination of maven plugins showed below.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <checkStarted>true</checkStarted>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>stop</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                     <goal>stop</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
     </executions>
    <configuration>
        <simpleLog>true</simpleLog>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

When i start maven goal *mvn install*, server runs as expected, but with wrong DB connection. I did not find way, how to set up, that i need use **src/test/resources** instead of **src/main/resources**.

Do you know how to set up this plugin in way? I'am open to suggestions of similar solutions, which is simple and do not contains 'lot of' frameworks.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation i found solution described below.

Three plugins were added into pom.

First plugin will start TomEE server for us.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>7.0.4</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>start</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>start</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <checkStarted>true</checkStarted>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>stop</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>stop</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <simpleLog>true</simpleLog>
</configuration>
```

Second one will replace proper resources and persistence files.

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.8</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy-test-persistence</id>
        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
        <configuration>
            <tasks>
                <!--backup the "proper" files-->
                <copy file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/resources.xml" tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/resources.xml.proper"/>
                <copy file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml" tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml.proper"/>

                <!--replace the "proper" files with the "test" version-->
                <copy file="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/META-INF/resources.xml" tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/resources.xml"/>
                <copy file="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml" tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml"/>

            </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>restore-persistence</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <configuration>
            <tasks>
                <!--restore the "proper" files -->
                <copy file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/resources.xml.proper" tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/resources.xml"/>
                <copy file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml.proper" tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
            </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Last plugin force 'clean' before install. Without this i had problem in case, when i forget clean project before install.

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>auto-clean</id>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```